# Is there a word that means that a computer is sending data to multiple computers?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means that a computer is sending data to multiple computers? I am trying to think of a word that's highly technical that means that specific meaning and perhaps more, but I can't think of any and the only word I can think of is transmit or send, but those words don't imply the data is sent to multiple computers. They only mean that the data is sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what kind of data transmission you have in mind, [**broadcast**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919) or [**multicast**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) might be the word you're looking for.

If you're not talking about communication protocols for sending data to multiple computers simultaneously, but only the fact that you're somehow sending data to multiple computers, then [**distribute**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distribute#English) might be a good verb. This verb is not very technical. It applies just as well to distributing leaflets to pedestrians, books to bookstores, and commercial products to retailers. If the data is a virus, you could say that one computer is [**spreading**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spread#English) the virus to multiple computers.

Comment: You may want **multicast**.

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, indeed! I'll add that.

Comment: Those are excellent but do have narrow technical meanings - they send to anyone in the appropriate network who wants to listen; like shouting in a room. 'Distributing' data would cover both of them, but would also cover talking to a selected audience, so to speak.

Comment: @simonatrcl Good point! I'll add that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating. Or 'networking' as a verb.

You can say 'communicating with various computers', and refer to the whole thing as 'the computer network'.

Because 'communicating' is a term that refers to the to and fro-ing of communication that you seem to wish to describe.

If they are in the network, they are 'communicating', if not, then not. Data tags like 'hey Fred' tell each node when to listen up.